# Mosquitto TLS, works with MQTTfx but not mosquitto_pub (tlsv1 alert unknown ca)

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

Quite strange issue

I have mosquitto broker working with TLS

It is correctly accessible by an MQTTfx client set up for 'Enable SSL/TLS, TLSv1.2, CA certificate file'

The same ca.crt file is used by a openwrt mosquitto client issuing

```
 # mosquitto_pub -h x.x.x.x -p 8883 --cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt -i 1.1.1.1 -t test -m 123 -d
```

it returns

```
Client 1.1.1.1 sending CONNECT
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

At the orher end, the broker, shows

```
OpenSSL Error: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure
Socket error on client (null), disconnecting.
```

What is messing me up is the fact that the MQTTfx client instead is accepted, and it's using the same certificate..!

```
New connection from y.y.y.y on port 8883.
New client connected from y.y.y.y as 180ce1c04c1944e1964608221efbcf0a (c1, k60).
Sending CONNACK to 180ce1c04c1944e1964608221efbcf0a (0)
```

Should mean that the certificate is valid and trusted... isn't it?
What's wrong then with the other client using the exact same certificate file ?!?!

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892976/mqtt-tls-ssl-publishes-subscribes-with-mqtt-spy-and-mqttfx-wha-are-the-right-pa#comment80752696_46892976

Answer (score 1):

...at the end using --insecure option did the job.

Means verification of the server hostname in the server certificate. 
Well it works, although using this option in a production environment potentially invalidates the use of encryption.

Comment: I know this is an old question. This is not working for me and I agree that it is not really a solution. I am using `mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.mysite.com -p 8883 --cafile cert/mqtt.mysite.com.cer --insecure -t home/bedroom/temp -m 23.4  -u "usr" -P "pwd"`. As for you it works with MQTTfx. Broker on Raspberry Pi Stretch. Client on macos